# which file contains my deep learning saved model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a deep learning model using tensorflow and i saved it as an "cnn.h5" file using keras. Now I have 3 files that have "cnn.h5" in their name but all of them contain a different extension. 
The three files are:

cnn.h5.meta

cnn.h5.index

CNN.h5.data-00000-of-00001

now can anyone tell me which one of the above files is the saved model? i have to load that  model in my GUI for testing.

 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog](https://stackabuse.com/tensorflow-save-and-restore-models/) post explains saving and restoring you can refer to it for details  a snippet of explanation for the type of saved files is as below.

> When saving the model, you'll notice that it takes 4 types of files to save it:
>
> > > ".meta" files: containing the graph structure
> > >
> > > ".data" files: containing the values of variables
> > >
> > > ".index" files: identifying the checkpoint